# Shoppify include image with max height in liquid template

Tags: shopify, liquid

I've got an template for an Shopify webshop what is written in Liquid. Now in that template it shows an image with the following tag.

```
{% include 'image', image_object: product.featured_image, alt: product.featured_image.alt, class: "w-full", disable_lazyload: true %}
```

This creates an nice image tag with srcset. But now I want to give the picture an maximum height. So that when an user uploads an really high foto, the product page is still nice.

But adding max-height with css gives an image with the wrong ratio. Trying the scrips following also didn't work:

```
{% include 'image', image_object: product.featured_image | image_url: 'x350', alt: product.featured_image.alt, class: "w-full", disable_lazyload: true %}

{% include 'image', image_object: product.featured_image, image_height: 350 alt: product.featured_image.alt, class: "w-full", disable_lazyload: true %}

{% include 'image', image_object: product.featured_image, image_url: 'x350', alt: product.featured_image.alt, class: "w-full", disable_lazyload: true %}
```

What is the correct tag to still use the include but give it to give the image an fixed height or an max height?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple by removing the `class: "w-full"` tag and having the max-height in css. So the tag became:

```
{% include 'image', image_object: product.featured_image, alt: product.featured_image.alt,  disable_lazyload: true %}
```

With an css like this:

```
img { max-height: 350px; }
```